# Why use Remember-Me Authentication if the are sessions?

Tags: spring-security

As far as I understand:

Both of them are sent as Cookies.

- Remember-Me token can live longer, than a session. But the session time
  can be also configured.
- Remember-Me token can live after Tomcat server has been restarted. Is this the only reason to use
  Remember-Me?

Answer (score 4):

You should see it more from the end-user's perspective, not so much the technical perspective. There's a trade-off between security and convenience.

- For `remember-me functionality` users usually have to tick a check-box, when logging in. And that will then automatically log you in *between* sessions (or rather: after your old session expired). More convenient, but 'potentially' more vulnerable.
- `Sessions` are (depending on the application) usually more shortlived (say, hours, in banking applications even just minutes, or until the user logs out) and you'll have to login again after your session expires. Less convenient, 'more' secure.

Comment: It's worth noting that remember-me functionality is an SSO strategy that layers on top of Spring Security, meaning that it's optional. It's also worth noting that the cookies are HTTP-Only, meaning that they are sent via the Spring Security headers, which are more secure because client side scripts cannot access the data. If you configure your Spring Security container to protect against CSRF, then the implementation basically becomes as bulletproof as you can make it before you get into OAuth2 tokenization techniques